# Foreach iteration,getting same values in a class

Tags: c#, linq

We have objects:

```
Foo a = new Foo;
a.Prop1 = XX;
a.Prop2 = YY;
a.Prop3 = 12;


Foo b = new Foo;
b.Prop1 = XX;
b.Prop2 = ZZ;
b.Prop3 = 3;

Foo c = new Foo;
c.Prop1 = FF;
c.Prop2 = DD;
c.Prop3 = 3;
```

And we have a list = `List<Foo> MyList= new List<Foo>()`
And all these objects are added to the list

While iterating through that list:

```
foreach(Foo _foo in Mylist)
{
   // I want to get the objects whose Prop1 value is
   // the same and add those to another list, what I want
   // to do exactly is actually grouping based on a property.
}
```

Comment: You cannot add classes to a list. You can add objects, not classes.

Comment: Also, your example code isn't correct. Show us what you really tried.

Comment: If you talk about real classes, you would have to use reflection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `GroupBy` to achieve this:

```
var myOtherList = list.GroupBy(x => x.Prop1)
                      .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                      .ToList();
```

`myOtherList` now contains one group per `Prop1` that appears multiple times and all items that have this `Prop1`.

If you don't care about the groups but only about the items they contain, you can change the query like this:

```
var myOtherList = list.GroupBy(x => x.Prop1)
                      .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                      .SelectMany(x => x)
                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, when you say `classes` i think you mean `objects` or instances of that class.

```
List<YourType> types = new List<YourType>();
List<YourType> types2 = new List<YourType>();

foreach(YourType yType in types)
{
    if(yType.Foo == "XX")
    {
       types2.Add(yType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with LINQ too:

```
Classlist.Where(x => x == whatever).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are free to use LINQ, this would accomplish..

```
        List<FooClass> originalList = new List<FooClass>(); // your original list containing the objects

        List<FooClass> newList = new List<FooClass>(); // Destination list where you want to keep adding the matching objects

        newList.AddRange(originalList.Where(el => string.Equals(el.Foo, "xx")));
```